# ssis literal single string qoute around a variable

Tags: ssis-2012

I would like to know how to put a single quote around a ssis vaiable, say I have a Variable name Variable, but the value is MyTable

```
@[User::Variable]
```

output =

```
MyTable
```

However, I want the output to look like this

```
'MyTable'
```

So how would the syntax look like on SSIS to accomplish this please?

Answer (score 1):

Found out by chance, not a fan of SSIS expression Syntax at all!!!

```
    "'"+@[User::TableName]+"'"
```